# dynamic generated remove button should remove its p tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm dynamically adding 3 fields on every "Add another input box" link, but now I'm stuck as to how should I remove the dynamically created row, onclick of that particular remove link. 
Here is what I have tried so far

```js
$(function() {
  var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
  var i = $('#p_scents p').length + 1;

  $('#addScnt').on('click', function() {
    $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text"  size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i + '" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i + '" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i + '" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label> <a href="#" class="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
    i++;
    return false;
  });

  $(".remScnt").on('click', function() {
    if (i > 2) {
      $(this).parents('p').remove();
      i--;
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<h2><a href="#" id="addScnt">Add Another Input Box</a></h2>

<div id="p_scents">
    <p id="p_scnt1">
        <label for="p_scnts"><input type="text"  size="20" name="p_scnt" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label>
        <label for="p_scnts"><input type="text"  size="20" name="p_scnt" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label>
        <label for="p_scnts"><input type="text"  size="20" name="p_scnt" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label>
    </p>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Please make sure library versions are the same.

Comment: Let me just verify this with you, you need to dynamically add inputs when the link is clicked, whoever this inputs are wrapped into a `p` tag and you want to remove that, is this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contents of your event handler are fine, the problem exists because the event handler doesn't get attached to your link. You can either use the `$(document).on('click', 'selector', function)` function or always add the event handler to newly created elements after they're created.

Here's an example with `.on`:

```js
$(function() {
  var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
  var i = $('#p_scents p').length + 1;

  $('#addScnt').on('click', function() {
    $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text"  size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i + '" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i + '" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i + '" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label> <a href="#" class="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
    i++;
    return false;
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.remScnt', function() {
    if (i > 2) {
      $(this).parents('p').remove();
      i--;
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<h2><a href="#" id="addScnt">Add Another Input Box</a></h2>

<div id="p_scents">
    <p id="p_scnt1">
        <label for="p_scnts"><input type="text"  size="20" name="p_scnt" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label>
        <label for="p_scnts"><input type="text"  size="20" name="p_scnt" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label>
        <label for="p_scnts"><input type="text"  size="20" name="p_scnt" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label>
    </p>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Also, for accessibility reasons you should avoid using `<a>` elements as buttons - what you should ideally do is using a `<button>` element and then styling it to look like a link.